# R function for inverse and transpose

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello not sure if the formula I am trying to figure out will come through clean but this is what I am looking at:
Assume Y: diameter and X: rings. What is〖(X^' X)〗^(-1) X^' Y ?

So I created a data frame from "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data"

I believe I need to just find the inverse of the transpose of diameter and diameter.
For the transpose I believe the formula is t(abalone.data$diameter)
For the inverse I believe I need to use the solve function but cannot find any online documentation on how to really use it that would work for this problem.

Any additional info you can provide to help solve the problem I would greatly appreciate it.
Here is the R code I used to set up this data frame

```
abalone.url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data"
abalone.data <- read.csv(abalone.url, header=FALSE)
names(abalone.data) <- c("sex", "length", "diameter", "height", "weight.shucked", "weight.viscera", "weight.shell", "rings")
```

Comment: Run `?solve` to find documentation on that function.

Answer (score 0):

That formula is the analytic expression for the Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) estimator, also the same for Maximum Likelihood estimator.

You can use a combination of `t()` for transposing vectors, `%*%` for matrix multiplicaton and `solve` for getting the inverse of a matrix. So you can do the following using a set of data from `mtcars`

```
X <- matrix(c(rep(1, length(mtcars$mpg)), mtcars$mpg), ncol=2)
Y <- mtcars$wt    
    
solve(t(X)%*%X) %*% (t(X)%*%Y)    
          [,1]
[1,]  6.047255
[2,] -0.140862
```

An alternative is using `crossprod`: `solve(crossprod(X), crossprod(X,Y))`

Since you are using OLS estimators, you can simple use `lm` function and get the same results

```
lm(Y~X[,-1])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      X[, -1]  
     6.0473      -0.1409
```

Take into account I added an intercept term.

If you want to get rid of the intercept, then run this:

```
X <-  mtcars$mpg
Y <- mtcars$wt    
solve(crossprod(X), crossprod(X,Y))
lm(Y~X-1)
```

Comment: Since you are already looking into this in depth, you might want to mention that `crossprod(X)` is a **faster** alternative to `t(X) %*% X`.